# Bounding Box Coordinates are given in different Projection - how do I find out which

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

All the layers in my application are EPSG:31466. However, if I retrieve the capabilites:

```
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities();

        OpenLayers.Request.GET({
            url: myUrl,
            success: function(e){

                var response = wms.read(e.responseText);
                var layerObj = response.capability.layers[0];  
                console.log(layerObj.llbbox);

            }
        }
```

The BoundingBox' Coordinates are given in a totally different format.

In EPSG:31466 I would expect them to be similar to `new OpenLayers.Bounds(363060,5770362,363496,5771118)`, but in fact they are like this: `[-23.015284514192917, 48.276782941782315, -22.953739137948624, 48.29765968309495]`.

Looks like a different format, but why and how do I change this?

---

```
    console.log(layerObj.llbbox);
    var my_extent=new OpenLayers.Bounds(layerObj.llbbox).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.displayProjection);
    console.log(my_extent);
```

Console Output:

```
 [-23.015284514192917, 48.276782941782315, -22.953739137948624, 48.29765968309495]

Object { left=-23.015284514193, bottom=48.276782941782, right=-22.953739137949, more...}
```

Comment: looks like the bounding box is coming from `Lat-Lon Bounding Box` and not from `Native Bounding Box`, which I want to have : http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html#bounding-boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's EPSG 4326. llbox means latlon-boundingbox. Every layer has to be published in 4326 but can often be requested in different crs's, so you get the llbbox always in 4326.
just reproject them with

```
.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466"));
```

for example

```
var my_extent=new OpenLayers.Bounds(-23.015284514192917, 48.276782941782315, -22.953739137948624, 48.29765968309495).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466"));
```

If transforming fails one reason can also be that you have not included proj4.js for this projection.

```
    var neu=new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([35.76180874190184, 7.0599674899119, 
36.38799280563133, 7.559116178088183]);

    console.log(neu.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466")));
```

Reprojecting should work if proj4.js is included. see console.log in this example:
[image]

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/using-proj4js.html

You can get the BBOX of your Layer also with

```
console.log(layerObj.bbox["EPSG:31466"]);
```

instead of

```
console.log(layerObj.llbbox);
```

Comment: looks like the transformation fails (look above).

Comment: have you already tried console.log(layerObj.bbox["EPSG:31466"]); instead of console.log(layerObj.llbbox); ?

Comment: nice. just added one more option in my answer to get the extent in 31466 by including proj4.js... (and merged my last comment also in the answer)